# Convert Linq to Sql query into better sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

So I need some with a sql query.  The sql generated from linq is very subpar it seems and the stored procedure times out.

Here's what i'm trying to do.

Two tables, look like this:

```
dbo.Links
-------------
Id
Url
Title
```

And another one that looks like this

```
dbo.Link_Counts
-----------------
Url
Count
```

What I would like to do is write a sql query that does this

```
var linkCounts = Links.GroupBy(x => x.Url)
                 .Select(grp => new Link_Counts 
                  {
                      Url = grp.First().Url,
                      Count = grp.Count()
                  });

InsertAllOnSubmit(linkCounts);
SubmitChanges();
```

The sql that I attempted to use that is partly generated from this is

```
    INSERT INTO Link_Counts (Url, Count)
SELECT (
    SELECT [t3].[URL]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t2].[URL]
        FROM [Links] AS [t2]
        WHERE (([t1].[URL] IS NULL) AND ([t2].[URL] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[URL] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t2].[URL] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[URL] = [t2].[URL]))
        ) AS [t3]
    ) AS [Url], [t1].[value] AS [Count]
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value], [t0].[URL]
    FROM [Links] AS [t0]
    GROUP BY [t0].[URL]
    ) AS [t1]
END
```

Where apparently is too long running for a stored procedure.

Any help would be greatful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write the SQL by hand:

```
insert into link_counts (url, count)
select url, count(0)
from links
group by url
```

Or, if you just want to fix the LINQ query to generate better SQL:

```
var linkCounts = 
    Links.GroupBy(x => x.Url)
         .Select(g => new Link_Counts
             {
                 Url = g.Key,
                 Count = g.Count()
             };
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need to insert the count for each url:

```
insert into Link_Counts (Url, Count)
select Url, Count(*)
from dbo.Links
group by Url
```